# no matching function for call to ‘normalize(cv::Point3f&)’ error

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm getting `no matching function for call to ‘normalize(cv::Point3f&)’` error in this code snippet using gcc 9.3.0 and OpenCV 4.3.0:

```
    cv::Point3f p{3, 0, 0}, q{0, 2, 0};
    p.cross(q);
    cv::normalize(p);
```

According to current documentation, both `cross` and `normalize` accept the same parameter type, which is `const Vec< _Tp, cn > &`. Why then call to `cross` compiles, but call to `normalize` doesn't?

**EDIT**

I know that `cv::normalize((Vec3f)p);` works. The question is why  this explicit conversion to `Vec3f` is necessary here, but not in case of `cross()`?

Comment: @Miki I'm looking for a normal vector not a norm.

Comment: @PaulJurczak the cross is a member function of [`Point3`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d6c/classcv_1_1Point3__.html#a4f8bf249885e00c31a4f63565bf4df15) and normalize is a free-function that takes a `Vec` and Point3 doesn't inherit from Vec. (`Point3::cross` and `Vec<T,3>::cross` are two different functions to the compiler)

Comment: @PeterT It makes sense, as much as implicit type conversion rules of C++ make sense to me ;-)

Comment: @PaulJurczak `cv::normalize` is a function template, if you don't fully specialize it then the compiler will just do template argument deduction, which does not do implicit type conversions for deduced types, if you want it to behave like a normal function call, you need to instantiate the function template like `cv::normalize<float,3>(p);`. Also, FYI the single argument version does not modify the input parameter, but returns a normalized version.

Comment: @PeterT Thanks, `cv::normalize<float,3>(p)` looks better than my `cv::normalize((Vec3f)p)`.

Answer (score 4):

`cv::norm(...)` gives you the norm (a scalar value) of your vector. You can normalize a vector by dividing by its norm.

Given two vector `p, q`, you can get the normal vector as:

```
cv::Point3f p{3, 0, 0}, q{0, 2, 0};
cv::Point3f r = p.cross(q);
cv::Point3f rn = r / cv::norm(r);
```

You can also use `cv::Vec3f` instead of `cv::Point`:

```
cv::Vec3f p{3, 0, 0}, q{0, 2, 0};
cv::Vec3f r = p.cross(q);
cv::Vec3f rn = r / cv::norm(r);
// or
cv::Vec3f rm = cv::normalize(r);
```

> The question is why this explicit conversion to Vec3f is necessary here

Because cv::normalized is defined for `cv::Vec_<Tp, 3>`, not for `cv::Point3_<Tp>`

```
template<typename _Tp, int cn> inline
Vec<_Tp, cn> normalize(const Vec<_Tp, cn>& v)
{
    double nv = norm(v);
    return v * (nv ? 1./nv : 0.);
}
```

Please note that it just divides the vector by its norm, as showed above for the `cv::Point3f` case.

> but not in case of cross()

`cross` is a method of the class `cv::Point3_`

Also note that `cv::Point3_` has an overloaded conversion operator for `cv::Vec`

```
//! conversion to cv::Vec<>
operator Vec<_Tp, 3>() const;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc for 4.3.0, you need to include `<opencv/core/matx.hpp>`, have you tried that?

I do also understand from the doc that you need to assign the return value, the input argument is const, and you need to do that also for the cross product. So it's going o be something like:

```
#include <opencv/core/matx.hpp>
...
cv::Point3f p{3, 0, 0}, q{0, 2, 0};
auto normalized = cv::normalize(p.cross(q));
```

--EDIT--
There's also a mismatch in the type (`Vec` instead of `Point`). This last version builds fine:

```
cv::Vec3f p{3, 0, 0}, q{0, 2, 0};
auto normalized = cv::normalize(p.cross(q)); // Defined only for Vec_
cv::Point3f p3 = normalized; // Get back a Point3f, or continue with a Vec?
```

Comment: I had all needed includes. Return value doesn't have to be assigned. I'm getting the same error with your example. Have you tried to compile it?